# Cannot install Intel Graphics UHD 620

Tags: graphics, intel

I'm using HP Probook G6 with Intel UHD 620 and I can't install Intel Graphics. I already tried with intel-graphics-tool, but I got error: 
[image]

And this is the output: 
https://pastebin.com/E0ZmMxiG

PS: I have elementary OS 5.0 Juno

Answer (score 2):

Whenever dealing with drivers, you first need to remember that elementary os 5.0 is based on Ubuntu 18.04. With this in mind, you might notice that the repository https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/, described in your screenshot, does not contain anything usable above Ubuntu 17.10. You should also know that elementary OS 5.0 already includes the appropriate MESA Intel drivers.

Running the command `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL` should output something like this:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.0.8
```

If, like me, you encountered some issues running some games using the intel graphics adapter, you might benefit from installing the Mesa Vulkan packages:

```
sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils vulkan-tools
```

That being said, if you really need the latest drivers, you could try using the oibaf drivers ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After the upgrade completes, running `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"` again should output the following:

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.0-devel (git-3e21e17 2019-12-02 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
```

EDIT: if, during the update process, you encounter some ppa errors, you might need to do some cleanup first (maybe you added some obsolete repository?). Just run the following command, replacing `name-of-the-repository` with the name of the one you have to remove:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:name-of-the-repository
sudo apt update
```

For example, to remove the one from your screenshot:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/intel-graphics-updates
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Unable to install vulkan-tools 
`davide@davide-hp:~/Scaricati$ sudo apt-get install vulkan-tools
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
E: Impossibile trovare il pacchetto vulkan-tools
davide@davide-hp:~/Scaricati$`

Output of `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"` :
`OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.1.2 - padoka PPA`

Comment: vulkan-tools is not essential, you can try running the command without it.

Comment: Also, if you add the oibaf ppa, make sure to remove the padoka ppa first.

Comment: After removing padoka ppa I tried to do: sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers vulkan-utils, but I already have last versions.

Comment: Update: I managed to update Open GL version. Now output of glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version" is: 

`OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 20.0.0-devel (git-dde7340 2019-12-03 bionic-oibaf-ppa)`

But the issue is that system doesn't recognize model of my integrated graphics card

Comment: Good, so the drivers are installed correctly. Now for the system not detecting the card... run the command `sudo lshw -C video | awk -F'product: ' '/product/{print $2}'` and add the output to your question. If it says 'Intel Corporation', it's ok. In the System Preferences -> About, mine says 'Intel Corporation Device 3e9b'. Do you have any performance or stability issues?

Comment: The output is: Intel Corporation. Sometimes there are some delays in transition/animation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your computer specifications it looks like it is a new model, as long as HP do not support windows 7 and 8 for it. What I recommend you is to update the OS to Hera and especially the kernel to 5.0 because it has a better hardware support for new models as it is written into the elementary.io website. If you decide to do this, the os can be upgraded using the AppCenter, but the kernel to be upgraded you have to execute in terminal

`sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`

as it is described at the end of the blog on https://blog.elementary.io/introducing-elementary-os-5-1-hera/

Also on the screenshot you provide I see that the problems are with xenial repositories, Juno is based on Bionic version of Ubuntu, that means you are trying to install older, non supported software.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my kernel to 5.0 but I still encounter problems with animations D: