# how to update openGl in elementary os

Tags: release-hera, updates, settings

Friends
How to upgrade OpenGL from version 2 to version 3.3 or higher.
thank you for your attention

```
xxx~$ glxinfo | grep -i opengl
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset (CTG)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 20.3.0-devel (git-2b977ad 2020-10-06 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 20.3.0-devel (git-2b977ad 2020-10-06 bionic-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: TRy this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21307/cannot-install-intel-graphics-uhd-620/21308#21308

Comment: I believe that you should google for the highest OpenGL version that is supported on your GPU. You cannot force all versions of OpenGL on all Intel's GPUs.